# IoC - Initialize object state in the constructor

Tags: c#, ioc-container

For every page request, I need to get some current user permissions data from the database and then use this information several times in the logic
(which is made of several objects)

I want to get data  from the database once per request, and reuse it where needed by injecting it.

Is the following the best way to do this?

1) define a object like this

```
class ApplicationUser : IApplicationUserProvider
{
    private UserPermissions _userPermissions;
    ...

    public ApplicationUser(IDatabase userService)
    {
        _userPermissions = userService.GetUserPermission(); // this would executed for every request once
    }

    UserRoles GetRoles()
    {
        return _userPermissions;
    }
}
```

2) define the ioc something like this

```
 var container1 = new Container(c =>
            {
        c.For<IDatabase>().Use<Database>();
        c.For<IApplicationUser>().Use<ApplicationUser >();
        c.For<IApplicationLogic1>().Use<ApplicationLogic1>(); // this has IApplicationUser in ctor
        c.For<IApplicationLogic2>().Use<ApplicationLogic2>(); // this has IApplicationUser in ctor
            });
```

3) the controller would be

```
void PageController(IApplicationLogic1 l1)
{
    l1.Process();
    l2.Process();   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `UserPermissions` information is runtime data, and as explained [here](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99), runtime data should not be injected or resolved during construction of the object graphs.

Instead, the call to `userService.GetUserPermission()` should be moved out of the constructor. For instance by delaying the call by using a `Lazy<T>`:

```
class ApplicationUser : IApplicationUserProvider
{
    private Lazy<UserPermissions> _userPermissions;

    public ApplicationUser(IDatabase userService) {
        _userPermissions = new Lazy<UserPermissions>(userService.GetUserPermission);
    }

    UserRoles GetRoles() {
        return _userPermissions.Value.GetRoles();
    }
}
```

Another option is to define a decorator on `IDatabase` that will implement the caching:

```
public class PerRequestCacheDatabaseDecorator : IDatabase
{
    private IDatabase _decoratee;

    public PerRequestCacheDatabaseDecorator(IDatabase decoratee) {
        _decoratee = decoratee;
    }

    public UserPermissions GetUserPermission() {
        var items = HttpContext.Current.Items;
        if (items["permissions"] == null)
            items["permissions"] = _decoratee.GetUserPermission();
        return (UserPermissions)items["permissions"];
    }
}
```

By wrapping the real database inside the `PerRequestCacheDatabaseDecorator`, you can simplify the `ApplicationUser` to the following:

```
class ApplicationUser : IApplicationUserProvider
{
    private IDatabase _userService;

    public ApplicationUser(IDatabase userService) {
        _userService = userService;
    }

    public UserRoles GetRoles() {
        return _userService.GetUserPermission().GetRoles();
    }
}
```

Now neither the `ApplicationUser` nor the `Database` class are concerned with this performance optimization, which is a good thing. The decorator allows us to plugin this performance optimization without having to change any of the existing classes.